# STDIN and STDOUT combining into one

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stdin

How to write and read simultaneously the output of stdin? Is it possible to make? So that when you write something, it at the same has to show your input.

I found and example which uses stdin and stdout and pipe but I dont know how to use it in my case

```
<input-file.txt commandA | commandB >output-file.txt
```

Comment: stdin is an input stream, and you should not write to it.  "the output of stdin" is a phrase which I do not understand.  What is "it" in the phrase "it at the same time has to show your input"?  I suspect you are conflating stdin, stdout, and the terminal.

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation. You are right, I have to give one command which writes and reads the output of writing. And they have to be separated using pipe..

Comment: If you want to write "one command", then what is "they"?   It sounds like you just want to write `cat | cat`!  Are you wanting to write a command that reads its own output?  You'll probably need a fifo.

Comment: oh sorry by they I mean stdin and stdout

Comment: So basically, the task is to use stdin and stdout and pipe

Comment: @WilliamPursell: on many platforms it is possible to use `write(2)` to write to fd 0 and `read(2)` to read from fd 1 (from C), it scares the heck out of people when they see it working.  A bad idea, but fun.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo Enter your answer:
 read variable
 echo ${variable}
```

It will ask you for a value, you enter it, and it will output it once you hit `Enter`.

**Update**

This will also work as one command:

```
read variable && echo ${variable}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I was looking for one command which shows the output from the command prompt...

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: @asel Updated my answer with a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks this works too, but my task is to use stdin and stdout redirection..((

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you...

```
cat < a > b
```

That's an input redirection from a, and an output redirection to b.
Is that what you wanted?

Try this.

```
cat
```

It will sit and wait for you, because by default the terminal is STDIN.

Type something and hit  - it will spit it back at you, because by default STDOUT goes to the console. It will continue to do this till you feed it an EOF char or break the program some other way, like a CTRL-C.

If you require a pipe,

```
cat | cat
```

will (pointlessly) do the same thing.

To combine them for gratuitous use of both pipes and redirections -

```
cat < a | cat > b
```

Can you give clearer requirements?

Comment: I am not sure.. So when you execute the command, you have to be able to write something and when you hit enter it will show you what you have written. So I have to use stdin and stdout and pipe